# What is the difference between Compare with BASE vs. WORKING TREE?

Tags: tortoisegit

#1 and #3 in this screensot.
What is BASE vs. WORKING TREE?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

`Compare with Working Tree` compares the selected file of the selected vsion against the currently checked out files (this is called working tree in Git).

`Compare with base` compares the selected file against the previous commit (i.e., it shows the changes of the current commit).

Comment: @clay-nichols Please consider to uvote/accept this answer if it helped you or leave a comment on what's still missing.